# Air control system in cabin

Tags: hvac, air, heater-control, cabin

2016 Air distribution functions fine on passenger side. Drivers side only blows hot air. Have not tried anything yet. Want to make sure I am looking at correct component.

Comment: has a kid played with the controls?

Answer (score -1):

It is called a blend door actuator. Or possibly a blend door itself may be stuck.